# What about PCI mmio access alignment?

Tags: kernel, memory-alignment, pci

I have a basic quesion about the alignment when access PCIe bar mmio space. Is the address accessed must be DW aligned and count must be DW aligned?

As far as I know, The address field of TLB ignore lower 2 bits and the unit of length field also is DW. So does it mean above question is Yes? Else will CPU handle unaligned access for mmio space?

I want to know wether below access illegal or not:
  - readb(bar0)
  - readb(bar0 + 1)
  - readl(bar0+1)

what transaction will happen on the PCIe
bus if issue a unaligned mmio access?

Answer (score 1):

If you look deeper into TLPs, you will see, that it has fields like first byte enable and last byte enable. Their purpose is to handle DW misalignments. Each one show which bytes from the 1st and last DW are masked out. Last byte enable is used only with memory accesses larger than 1 DW.

For example:
If you are trying to read 1 byte at offset 0x3, it will be translated into DW read at offset 0 with first byte enable set to 0x4 (last_be will be 0x0, since it is 1 DW access). Completion with data then should have unnecessary bytes masked out.

Another example:
If you are trying to read 1 DW from offset 1, it will be translated into read of 2 DWords with 1st be and last be set to ignore 1st byte in 1st DW and last 3 bytes in 2nd DW.

Regards,
Mateusz.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. For the example #2, I have some experimental on my pc. If read across DWORD boundary, I get some intersting value, like readl(bar0+2). For some device, I get a cyclic shifted value of the first  DWORD, while some device return all FF. I read the register by devmem2 tool. Is this result by design or just the device cannot handle the BEs?   It seems that with  BE the device can process any unaligned access.                My question on maillist https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/5/28/89

Comment: Are you sure, that device that is returning all FF is not in D3 at the time of reading its memory?

Comment: I am sure. Since read aligned address it returns correct values, not FF. One of the tried devices is intel integrated GPU.

Comment: That's interesting. In this case, I guess, you need to consult the behavior with HW provider. And, if possible to attach one, look at the TLPs using some PCI protocol analyzer to fully understand what is happening on the bus.

Comment: I didn't have a PCI bus analyzer on hand. I will have a try when i found one.